# How the list is stitched according to the index value

Tags: python, list

There has a list `A['a','b','c']`  another struct B,
How to use A get below fommat?

`B[A[0]][A[1]][A[2]]`

Comment: Did you mean `A = ['a', 'b', 'c']`?  Also, what do you mean struct B? I'm not sure I understand your operation `B[A[0]][A[1]][A[2]]

`

Comment: Not everyone's English is perfect, but you should at least try to write a clear example and try to make clear what your problem is exactly. What is `B`? What do you need exactly?

Comment: Are you looking for the following? `A = ['a', 'b', 'c']; B = list(map(list, A)); print(B)` result `[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
>>> A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> B = list(map(lambda x: [x], A))
>>> B
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per comment OP was looking for:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
B = list(map(list, A))
print(B)
```

Result

`[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]`

This could also be achieved with list comprehension, though this is more verbose.

```
[[x] for x in A]
```

Comment: On second thoughts I prefer list comprehension. Much clearer to read.

Comment: Wait, `'abc'` will become `['a','b','c']`

Comment: For map... listcomp works